# How to create an UILabel with a red corner?

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, drawrect

My goal is to create an `UILabel` with the top left corner red (a visible triangle with a side of 10-15 points). How can I do it?

I tried subclassing an `UILabel` and to override `drawRect` but I had no success. Not only I didn't get any red corner I also lost the `label.text` that is showed if I do not override `drawRect`.

```
-(void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect
{

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx,0,0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx,10,0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx,0,10);
CGContextClosePath(ctx);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx,50,0,0,1);
CGContextFillPath(ctx);

}
```

Thanks!

Nicola

P.s. I wanted to add an image of the label I want to create but I need a reputation of at least 10 point to add it :(

Comment: Have you tried here for help : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it would have been sufficient to read the documentation of the function you're using. You made assumptions instead, which turned out to be wrong (no surprise).

The `CGContextMoveToPoint()` function begins a new subpath **without drawing.** If you want to draw a line, then... well... use the function that *draws a line:*

```
CGPoint points[] = {
    CGPointMake(0, 0),
    CGPointMake(10, 0),
    CGPointMake(0, 10),
    CGPointMake(0, 0)
};
CGContextAddLines(ctx, points, sizeof(points) / sizeof(points[0]));
```

Comment: I thought the drawing was handled by the CGContextFillPath(ctx).

Comment: @NicolaP. Don't "think", read. `CGContextFillPath(ctx);` is still needed, though.

Comment: Your code does exactly was I was looking for, thank you. The only problem is that it draws correctly the triangle on the top left but the label doesn't show anymore its text. Any hint?